# Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function that satisfies the relation $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$. Prove $f(x) \equiv 0$ or $f(x) = e^{ax}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

My partial solution is as follows:

> Let $y$ be the independent variable and $x$ a constant;
> differentiating with respect to y, we get $$\frac {d}{dy}f(x+y)= \frac {d}{dy}f(x)f(y)=f(x)f^{'}(y) \\ \therefore f^{'}(x+y) = f(x)f^{'}(y)$$
> Now, if we let $y=0$, we get $f^{'}(x)=f^{'}(0)f(x)$ for all values of
> x. We can now consider x as the independent variable and represent
> $f^{'}(0)$ as a constant $a$. There are two cases to consider:
>
> 1. If $a \neq 0$, we get the differential equation $f^{'}(x) = af(x)$ which has the solution $y = ce^{ax}$, where c is an arbitrary constant.
> 2. If $a = 0$, then $f^{'}(x) = 0$, which implies f(x) is a constant with an arbitrary value of $u$. Then, the given relation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ can be re-written as $$u(1-u)=0$$ which implies that $u=0$ or $u = 1$

Now, from my solution it seems that $f(x) = 1$ is valid candidate that satisfies all of the given conditions. $f(x) = 1$ is differentiable and it also satisfies the given relation $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$. However, I was asked to proved that the only two functions that satisfy the given relations are $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = ce^{ax}$. Is there something obvious I'm missing, or is there a logical flaw in my argument?

Comment: Are you missing that $1 = e^{0x}$?

Comment: $ce^{ax+ay} = ce^{ax} ce^{ay}$ implies $c=c^2$ so you shouldn't get two arbitrary constants.

Comment: Just let c=1 and a=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were asked to do is to prove that there are no other functions satisfying given conditions than those two functions given. Meanwhile, $f(x)=1$ is just a special case of $f(x)=ce^{ax}$, for $c=1$, $a=0$. So you haven't found a new function that is different than those that you were given, and you haven't proven (or disproven) the theorem you were given.

Comment: I have a follow up question. I actually made a typo when I first asked the question: my textbook wants me to prove that the only functions that satisfy the given conditions are $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = e^{ax}$. However, my solution has effectively shown that the functions that satisfy the given conditions can be represented as $f(x) = ce^{ax}$, as $f(x) = 0$ is also just a special case of $ce^{ax}$ where c = 0. Why does my textbook give the solution as $f(x) = 0$ or $f(x) = e^{ax}$? Doesn't that mean the textbook is missing some functions that satisfy the given conditions?

Comment: No, if $c$ is different than $0$ or $1$, it doesn't actually satisfy condition $f(x++y)=f(x)f(y)$. So you can say that all the solutions are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=e^{ax}$, or that all the solutions are $f(x)=ce^{ax}$ where $c\in\{0,1\}$; both ways are good.